# How can I disable the "unused attribute" warning when using Serde library?

Tags: json, rust, deserialization, serde

In addition to disabling the warning, why does it happen?

```
use serde_json::from_str;
use serde_json::error::Result;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct Config {
    #[serde(rename="cudaBlasDylibPath")]
    pub cuda_blas_dylib_path: String,
}

impl Config {
    pub fn new() -> Result<Config> {
        from_str("{}")
    }
}
```

> src/config.rs:4:10: 4:21 warning: unused attribute, #[warn(unused_attributes)] on by default
>   src/config.rs:4 #[derive(Deserialize)]

Adding `#[allow(unused_attributes)]` doesn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the full output from the compiler:

```
src/main.rs:10:10: 10:21 warning: unused attribute, #[warn(unused_attributes)] on by default
src/main.rs:10 #[derive(Deserialize)]
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:10:10: 10:21 note: in this expansion of #[derive_Deserialize] (defined in src/main.rs)
```

What this means is that the warning is within the code for the `impl` generated by the `#[derive]` attribute. However, it's hard to understand what's going on without seeing the code!

Fortunately, we can ask the compiler to show us the generated code. We need to pass additional parameters to `rustc`, specifically `-Z unstable-options --pretty=expanded`. If you're using Cargo, delete the compiled crate or run `cargo clean` (Cargo does nothing if the target is up to date), then run this command:

```
$ cargo rustc -- -Z unstable-options --pretty=expanded > src/main-expanded.rs
```

We can then try to compile `src/main-expanded.rs` with `rustc`. If you're using Cargo, use the command Cargo prints when you run `cargo build --verbose` (when the target is not up to date), but replace the name of the root source file with the new file we just generated – or you can just swap your `main.rs` or `lib.rs` with the expanded source. It might not always work, but when it does, it can provide some valuable insight.

We now get a clearer picture of the situation:

```
src/main-expanded.rs:17:5: 17:43 warning: unused attribute, #[warn(unused_attributes)] on by default
src/main-expanded.rs:17     #[serde(rename = "cudaBlasDylibPath")]
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main-expanded.rs:20:1: 20:25 warning: unused attribute, #[warn(unused_attributes)] on by default
src/main-expanded.rs:20 #[automatically_derived]
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here, the warning on the `#[serde]` attribute is probably caused by the fact that the struct no longer has the `#[derive(Deserialize)]` attribute, which is what processes the attribute. Also, it's not part of the expansion of the `#[derive(Deserialize)]` attribute, so that's not the attribute the original warning complained about.

It looks like the `#[automatically_derived]` attribute is the culprit here. This attribute appears to be used mainly by rustdoc (the documentation generation tool), but it has no meaning when compiling.

The implementation of `#[derive]` for derivable traits known to `rustc` emits the attribute like this:

```
let attr = cx.attribute(
    self.span,
    cx.meta_word(self.span,
                 InternedString::new("automatically_derived")));
// Just mark it now since we know that it'll end up used downstream
attr::mark_used(&attr);
```

My guess is that serde doesn't call the `mark_used` function, which is what causes the warning. The [only](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/blob/f474c57881444346f431bb6f2c978f3a06f0af73/serde_codegen/src/ser.rs#L62-L71) [occurrences](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/blob/f474c57881444346f431bb6f2c978f3a06f0af73/serde_codegen/src/de.rs#L67-L76) of "automatically_derived" in serde's source code are in invocations of the `quote_item!` macro, which probably doesn't emit a call to `mark_used` (and it should probably not do it either).

Comment: I think you can run `cargo rustc -Z unstable-options --pretty=expanded`. No need to extract `rustc` command from the verbose output.

Comment: Thank you for the such complete and serious explanation. The only missing answer is about how to fix that.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev: Thanks for the info. Actually, you need to put `--` before the arguments to pass to `rustc`, and then, Cargo will not run `rustc` if the target is up to date.

Comment: @ababo, I think this is likely a problem with serde itself. It probably makes sense to report this issue to its issue tracker.